# Append output in task scheduling

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using `sendOutputTo` [in task scheduling](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#task-output), we can store a task output in a file:

```
$schedule->command('test')->everyMinute()->sendOutputTo(storage_path('test'));
```

But I don't wan't to store only the last execution, I need a log. How can I log a scheduled task output in a single file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Isn't `appendOutputTo` what you're looking for?

```
$schedule->command('test')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo(storage_path('test'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the laravel system logs,

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#logging

or you can access to Monolog and create your own custom log

this link you can see how to separate the log into multiple files
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/advance-logging-with-laravel-and-monolog

Comment: I don't see any methods related to the Laravel logging system on the `Event` class returned by the `Schedule` methods.